# Need to change background color of month drop down in jquery datepicker on hover

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

[drop down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrStt.png)
I am using jquery-ui datepicker. I need to change the background color of drop down item from blue to gray on hover.
[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B92hX.png) follwing is my code

```
    <head><meta charset="utf-8"> <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Display month &amp; year menus</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body> 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: share a fiddle if you have any

Comment: What have you tried? None of us can help you unless I have something to work with, in particular a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). A great way to explain this is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Also, do check out the [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931) and [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: Oh, and to clarify: 1) please post applicable code here, and 2) There's little we can help with without the applicable HTML/CSS/JS + jQuery code here also.

Comment: I have added my code now. kindly check it and suggest a solution for my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
$("option").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", "grey");
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", "blue");    
    }
});
```

However, this will also apply to any other `option` you have on the page

Comment: i have tried it, but its not working :( I have added my code., Kindly check it once

Comment: Unfortunately, looking around, there is no "easy" way to do this with jQuery or CSS. Due to the browser defaulting the background of hovered elements not the plugin. The best option I can find is to use another jQuery plugin called "select2" (this can be used with datepicker but can also be used to function exactly like datepicker with easier styling)